# bootstrap popover: reload content with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I'm having trouble reloading content of a bootstrap popover with ajax.
Here's some code: http://pastie.org/3960102

The second ajax request (when I click on "a.close") returns an updated content (I can see it in the console), but it is not loaded inside the popover.

I looked around for solutions, none of them seem to work.

What else can I try?
Thank you

Answer (score 8):

Instead of resetting the `data-content` attribute, you are able to directly access the popover tooltip content.

Replace the following line:

```
t.attr('data-content', r);
```

with this working code:

```
t.data('popover').tip().html(r);
```

**Update 2012**

As [Pigueiras](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1004046/pigueiras) pointed out in his comment, that would destroy the default template for the popover. A better solution is to replace the contents of `.popover-content`:

```
t.data('popover').tip().find('.popover-content').empty().append(r);
```

**Update 2016**

Thanks to another comment, here is the working code for Bootstrap 3:

```
t.data('bs.popover').tip().find('.popover-content').empty().append(r);
```

Comment: This was very helpful for me, but if you don't want to remove the default template for the popover you should do something like: `t.data('popover').tip().find(".popover-content").empty().append(r);`

Comment: For bootstrap 3 versions you need to swap:    `t.data('.popover')` with `t.data('bs.popover')`

Answer (score 5):

Why `empty()` and then `append()` when you can just replace?

```
t.data('popover').tip().find('.popover-content').html(r);
```

EDIT:

Also, the first approach is correct and works fine (bootstrap 2.1) when popover is already initialized and you want to change the contents on the fly. You just have to call `'show'` again for the popover to refresh (content and position):

```
t.attr('data-content', r);
t.popover('show');
```

Comment: also works in bootstrap 3, although only using `.attr()` works as per your example, `.data()` doesn't

Answer (score 3):

After hours' search, I figured it out. For Bootstrap 3, you can use code below. More references are: 
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/11528 and [Bootstrap popover content cannot changed dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13564782/bootstrap-popover-content-cannot-changed-dynamically) 
    `if($element.data('bs.popover')) {
      $element.data('bs.popover').options.content = 'NEW CONTENT';
    }`

Comment: Thanks buddy. Out of all solutions, this one is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem, I resolve it with this trick, the code is verbose and just an exemple, optimize it !

```
// functions container
var doc = 
{
    doPopover : function( item_id, title, content )
    {
        // get jq item
        var item = $('#' + item_id );

        // the trick to "refresh content" in every call
        item.attr('data-content', content);

        // popover
        item.popover(
        {
            title   :   title,
            trigger :   'manual'
        }).popover('show');
    },

    popoverFirstCall : function()
    {
        this.doPopover('myDiv', 'Title', 'MyContent1');
    },

    popoverSecondCall : function()
    {
        var content = 'xxx'; // get the content in Ajax

        this.doPopover('myDiv', 'Title', content);
    }
}

// call funcs in your views
$(document).ready(function()
{
    // first popover with first content
    doc.popoverFirstCall();

    // this event wich call the ajax content and refresh popover. 
    $('#button').on('click', $.proxy(doc, 'popoverSecondCall'));
});
```

I suppose the trick is the same to refresh title also.

If you have a better solution, plz tell me !

EDIT :

I continued investigation,

we can see on plugin code :

```
getContent: function () {
      var content
        , $e = this.$element
        , o = this.options

      content = $e.attr('data-content')
        || (typeof o.content == 'function' ? o.content.call($e[0]) :  o.content)

      return content
    }
```

so, content is taken on attr "data-content", or on options given at the first call (instanciation) of popover.

But, actually, probleme is, options are cached and not refresh on every call, so wa have to use :

```
$('item_id').attr('data-content', 'some content'); // and warning, it is different than
$('item_id').data('content', 'some content');
```

And bootstrap get the attr way.

Same for title :

```
getTitle: function () {

      var title
        , $e = this.$element
        , o = this.options

      title = $e.attr('data-original-title')
        || (typeof o.title == 'function' ? o.title.call($e[0]) :  o.title)

      return title
    }
```

So, doPopover function could be :

```
    doPopover : function( item_id, title, content )
    {
        // get jq item
        var item = $('#' + item_id );

        // the trick to "refresh content" in every call
        item.attr('data-content', content); // do not use data() way.
        item.attr('data-original-title', title);

        // popover (trace first call if you want)
        item.popover(
        {
            trigger :   'manual'
        });

        item.popover('show);
    }
```

Work fine for me.

Comment: item.attr('data-content', content);  works! Thanks! Using Bootstrap v2.0.4

Answer (score 0):

This work form me:
Inizialize popover on document ready (data is a json with HTML and size of element found)

```
     $.ajax({
url: "/alpha/annuncio/scegliGestione",
success: function (data) {
    $('#notifiche').popover(
        {
            title:"Le tue notifiche",
            placement:'bottom',
            trigger:'manual'
        });
    $('#notifiche').find(".badge").text(data.size);

}
```

});

On the trigger event of popover you must in sequence toggle the popover (show or hide instead), make popover-content empty and finally append data.html

```
$("#notifiche").click(function(){

     $.get("/alpha/annuncio/scegliGestione", function(data) {
         $('#notifiche').popover('toggle')
         $("body").find('.popover-content').empty()
         $("body").find('.popover-content').append(data.html);

         $('#notifiche').find(".badge").text(data.size);
     });
    /* */

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Update from 2024 for Bootstrap 5.

To update the popover content after created the popover instance, you can use the `setContent` method:

```
// getOrCreateInstance example
const popover = bootstrap.Popover.getOrCreateInstance('#example') // Returns a Bootstrap popover instance

// setContent example
popover.setContent({
  '.popover-header': 'another title',
  '.popover-body': 'another content'
})
```

Related docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/popovers/#methods